# Flask flask_ldap3_login LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE

Tags: flask, ldap

`config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'LEVEL'` searches only the objects in `LDAP_USER_DN` but i want to search its sub OUs as well.

What should be the `LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE` to search the Sub OUs as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the search scope to **`SUBTREE`** to search the sub entries as well.

Flask relies on [The ldap3 project](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html) in which are defined the following search context :

> - **BASE**: retrieves attributes of the entry specified in the *search_base*.
> - **LEVEL**: retrieves attributes of the entries contained in the
>     *search_base*. The base must reference a container object.
> - **SUBTREE**:
>     retrieves attributes of the entries specified in the *search_base* and
>     all subordinate containers downward.